# Hazelcast 3.6.2 Eviction Map not working with Spring and max-size-policy as PER_NODE in 3.6.2

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to get Map eviction max-size="4" PER_NODE working on Hazelcast 3.6.2 spring. This beneath is my map defined in spring.

```
<hz:map name="sfdRequestMap" in-memory-format="OBJECT" eviction-policy="LRU" max-size="4" max-size-policy="PER_NODE" eviction-percentage="25">
</hz:map>
```

I've also checked if this eviction policy is actually set for the map defined and it is. Also evict after seconds works for that map, but eviction on overriding max size doesn't. I am using hazelcast 3.6.2. I've also tried removing in-memory-format, changing eviction policy etc etc.

Expected behavior is that when the map exceeds the amount of items (more then 4) the eviction would start. The actual behaviour is that the eviction never starts.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: what's the behaviour you are observing? entries are not evicted I presume. is this correct?

Comment: This is correct :)

Comment: I've tested it with 10 entries for additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hazelcast Map internally does eviction on partition basis, that means when you use `PER_NODE` policy with a maxSize of 5000, it *translates that maxSize to partition-max-size* by using this equation
 `partition-max-size = maxSize * memberCount / partitionCount`. And when entry-count in that partition exceeds `partition-max-size`, eviction starts on that partition. Min value for `partition-max-size` is internally set `1` not to evict every added entry. So `partitionCount` is the minimum settable max-size (default partition-count is 271).

Comment: So if I have 4 members within my hazelcast cluster and you want to have 20 items within my cache, the maxSize should be: 271/ 4* 20 = +/-1360? Where did you find this? Is there any documentation available?

Comment: You can see it documented here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-reference-manual/blob/49371def48db9b3de56868665605032ad9e0403c/src/Map-Eviction.md#understanding-map-eviction